# Join on value from object in jsonb array

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
stone_data     | ...
---------------+----
{[...], [...]} | ...
```

My stone data is jsonb and looks like this:

```
[{
  "Quantity": 2,
  "SKU": "abc123"
}, {
  "Quantity": 1,
  "SKU": "def456"
}]
```

I then have another table that looks like this:

```
sku (string) | ... | ...
-------------+-----+----
abc123       | ... | ...
def456       | ... | ...
```

The first table is called `settings` and the second table is called `accent_stones`. I'm trying to select some rows from `settings` and join `accent_stones` on the stone sku. I'm close, but I can't quite get it working:

```
SELECT *
FROM settings
LEFT JOIN accent_stones
ON accent_stones.sku = ANY(jsonb_array_elements(stone_data) ->> 'SKU');
```

I'm also wondering if this is going to be something I need to a `FULL JOIN` for instead, but I haven't figured that out yet since I haven't gotten the join working. I get this error:

```
ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
```

I understand the error, but I can't figure out how to either use something besides `ANY` or turn my result set into an array.

Comment: which output are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should preferably cross join `jsonb_array_elements` in the from clause. This will allow you to refer to the elements of the json in the select clause.

```
SELECT s.* , j->>'SKU' ,j->> 'Quantity',a.* 
  FROM settings s cross join jsonb_array_elements(stone_data) as j
     LEFT JOIN accent_stones a ON a.sku = j->> 'SKU'
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=32359e021446eed0ad03c3c139accb5c)

Comment: This is a really nice added bit of information, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, `jsonb_array_elements()` returns a set, not an array. So you could go with `IN` and a subquery.

```
SELECT *
       FROM settings
            LEFT JOIN accent_stones
                      ON accent_stones.sku IN (SELECT e->>'SKU'
                                                      FROM jsonb_array_elements(stone_data) ja (e));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8765c54b4a3e69e2a13035978bce834a)